# Windows Server Tesla/GPU Hosting

Tags: windows, gpu, hosting, cuda, gpgpu

I have a Windows calculation-intensive solution that uses NVidia's GPGPU (CUDA).

I am looking to host my application on the cloud and expose it via a Web service.
The only host I found was AWS, but it does it on Linux CentOS.

I want to find an online host that supports:

**1 - NVidia GPUs, specifically Tesla (Tesla M2090 or Tesla M2075).**

**2 - Using Windows Server 2008 R2 or 2012.**

**3 - Virtual or Dedicated.**

Are you aware of any host that fits my 3 points above?

Comment: EC2 [does offer](http://aws.amazon.com/windows/) GPU computing for windows.

Comment: You are right, I have watched an old demo which only showed a CentOS, but I am still interested in more resources.